# Identifying the sentence structure of a complex sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

I was given an excerpt from an essay about how we understand a "good life."

For context, the author was talking about how ancient Greek theorists would not distinguish between ethical and political matters.

> "The ideology of civic or republican humanism sees each in terms of
> the other: for me to exercise virtue, to realize my powers and
> capacities as a self-determining being, just is among other things for
> me to participate with others in the running of the polis."

The sentence is long and confusing, and I was asked to look at the second part of this sentence (beginning with "for me to exercise...") to identify the sentence structure. I have no idea! I am having trouble identifying the subject and verb. I've been reading this sentence over and over, but nothing seems clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler form:
(For me to exercise virtue) is (for me to participate in running society).

That is, if I participate in running the polis (society), I am exercising virtue (being good).

The phrase *among other things* should be set off with commas. It means there are other things you need to do to be virtuous. The word *just* could be dropped; it seems to say that it's all very simple, and it may contradict *among other things*.

It *is* a confusing sentence.